# POST operations not working from an IIS deployed web application

Tags: c#, iis

I have a web application which talks to a local service (also mine) and produces results from the RESTful calls.

I have deployed the web application through IIS 7 on my system.

So far it looks fine, except that I am not able to perform POST operations, they just seem like NOP's.

Although, when I install VS 2012 on the machine the POST operations start working. I am not sure what exact thing the VS 2012 install sets which causes the POST operations to work.

Any hints?

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code.  Post the error rather than your interpretation of the results.  What does firebug or similar network analysis tool say?

Comment: The specific code which is not working:
<a href="#" data-bind="visible: (status == '0' || status == '3'), click: function() {My.AAA.ViewModel.Task.verifyTask($data.id);}">Verify |</a>

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable POST operations in your **web.config** file. A simple implementation is demonstrated below

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Tried this, but does not seem to work. My link (POST) is working on the machine which contains VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to inlcude this in your config file:

```
   <webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: Getting an error: "Could not find schema information for element 'webServices'"